# Looping over lists in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, variable-assignment

I have two lists with numbers.

```
newlist      = [506.5, 133.0, 11104.2]
totalcolumns = [9.2, 10024.5, 610.0, 1100.0]
```

I want to loop over both lists and format the numbers in the same way:

```
myformatlists = [newlist, totalcolumns]

for i in range(0,len(myformatlists)):
     myformatlists[i] = ['{0:,}'.format(x) for x in myformatlists[i]]
     myformatlists[i] = [regex.sub("\.0?$", "", x).replace(".", "_").replace(",", ".")
```

printing

```
print(str(myformatlists[i])
```

gives the correct new values

but

```
print(str(newlist))
print(str(totalcolumns))
```

still gives the old lists.
Why doesn't my for-loop assign the values to the listname in myformatlists[i]?

How can I assign the output of the for-loop to the list in myformatlists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myformatlists[i] = ['{0:,}'.format(x) for x in myformatlists[i]]
```

rebinds `myformatlists[i]`, it does not alter the original item of `myformatlists`.

You can perform an inplace update of `myformatlists[i]` using slice notation:

```
myformatlists[i][:] = ['{0:,}'.format(x) for x in myformatlists[i]]
```

This will mutate the original list.

But note that there is a problem with the re code where `x` is not defined becaue the list comprehension is incomplete:

```
myformatlists[i] = [regex.sub("\.0?$", "", x).replace(".", "_").replace(",", ".")
```

It should be `re.sub` and perhaps the rest should be:

```
myformatlists[i] = [re.sub("\.0?$", "", x).replace(".", "_").replace(",", ".") for x in myformatlists[i]]
```

Comment: Thanks :) The only thing that I had to do was to change `myformatlists[i]` to `myformatlists[i][:]`, isn't it?

Comment: @Reman: yes. and fix the second list comprehension (but that's probably a typo anyway).

Comment: no it's not a type. I use the regex module and not the re module. I forgot to mention `import regex` in my example. Thanks for your great answer!